# WPRIG WordPress local server silently failing to run site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying my hand at wordpress theme development with WPRig (on WAMP server).
After installing it as per the tutorials, I'm trying to run it with "npm run build". The gulp and composer tasks seem to complete without any issues and finally it says that the local server (and browser-sync) has started on my localhost, however when I hit the url on my browser(chrome/IE), it spins for a minute and times out.

I couldn't find any issue similar to this anywhere on google/stackoverflow or on the github issues page (https://github.com/wprig/wprig). I hate it when things fail silently !!

There is just one error message right at the start, however I assume the fallback mechanism takes over, hence there is no exit from the build process:
[00:15:00] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[00:15:00] Requiring external module babel-register

Finally I tried to investigate with gulp's verbose mode and got he below output.

```
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\daddycool  (wprig@1.0.4)
λ node --inspect-brk .\node_modules\.bin\gulp --verbose
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/439d987c-37d1-46f2-81c3-1919a704d817
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\daddycool\node_modules\.bin\gulp:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

### Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

Other things tried - I have nuked my npm cache...

```
λ gulp -v
[00:31:53] Failed to load external module @babel/register
[00:31:53] Requiring external module babel-register
[00:31:54] CLI version 2.0.1
```

### [00:31:54] Local version 4.0.0

This is the version of my gulpfile :https://github.com/wprig/wprig/blob/1c8966ec5727323e83e382588cf28aa7a958e51a/gulpfile.babel.js

Answer (score 0):

OK, I went back and looked at Mr. Morten's videos again on the setup and realized that i was doing something wrong.

Essentially, I had no virtual domain for my homepage and my site was basically at http://localhost/wordpress
Whereas, I just only changed the name of proxyURL from wprig:8888 to wordpress:8888 which was obviously wrong. After changing that to 'localhost/wordpress', everything works.

Sorry, I am a beginner (when it comes to web development), so this wasn't obvious to me.